# Typescript enum with multiple string values

Tags: typescript, enums

I struggled find a way to get my enum variable name and the string part for the display name (to use both the variable name and string 'display' name)

I wanted this because I would use the variable name in my filter queries, and the display name to show on the front end.

So I found a way to create an object to act as an enum, and thought id just add it here for you guys.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

So Instead of creating an enum, just create an object in this format.

```
export const RewardCategory = { 
  swapPoints:  {variable: 'swapPoints', display: 'Swap Points' },
  charity: {variable: 'charity', display: 'Charity' },
  discountVouchers: {variable: 'discountVouchers', display: 'Discount Vouchers' }
}
```

Then, simply use it like this.

```
RewardCategory.swapPoints.display
```

or

```
 RewardCategory.swapPoints.variable
```

Comment: I would use `const` instead of `let`.

Also you can declare each `RewardCategory` value `as EnumLayout` (which shouldn't be named "enum"). Then, you can just use `RewardCategory.swapPoints.display`.

Answer (score 27):

Instead of creating an Interface or an Enum you can use a class with private constructor. And create `static readonly` instances of your class.

```
export class RewardCategory {
  public static readonly swapPoints = new RewardCategory('swapPoints', 'Swap Points');
  public static readonly charity = new RewardCategory('charity', 'Charity');
  public static readonly discountVouchers = new RewardCategory('discountVouchers', 'Discount Vouchers');

  private constructor(public readonly variable: string, public readonly displayName: string) {
  }
}
```

Then you could use it like this:

```
RewardCategory.charity.displayName
```

or

```
RewardCategory.charity.variable
```

Comment: Upvoting this becuase it is easier to consume.

Comment: @AnishUnnikrishnan no, it is not. classes in typescript are heavy functions when they get compiled and passed around and even this piece of code is unneccesarily bloated and the recursion is confusing.

Answer (score 2):

Enums are encoded as plain javascript objects so you can do the following:

```
enum Numbers {
    one = 'number one',
    two = 'the second number'
}

for (const key in Numbers)
    console.log(`key: ${key}, value: ${Numbers[key]}`);

function getTheKeyFromTheValue(value: string) {
    for (const key in Numbers)
        if (Numbers[key] === value)
            return key;

    return undefined; // Couldn't find it
}
```